# How to validate select box based on the other text box value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have table like this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th><select name ="select1" >options</select></th>
    <th><select name ="select2" >options</select></th>
    <th><select name ="select3" >options</select></th>
    <th><select name ="select4" >options</select></th>
    <th><select name ="select5" >options</select></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type ="text" name="distance1"></td>
    <td><input type ="text" name="distance2"></td>
    <td><input type ="text" name="distance3"></td>
    <td><input type ="text" name="distance4"></td>
    <td><input type ="text" name="distance5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type ="text" name="distance1"></td>
    <td><input type ="text" name="distance2"></td>
    <td><input type ="text" name="distance3"></td>
    <td><input type ="text" name="distance4"></td>
    <td><input type ="text" name="distance5"></td>
  </tr>
  .
  .
  .
  N rows
</table>
```

Now I want if the distance1 is filled then a option must  be selected from select1 select box, it applies to all the input text boxes.

How can I do this in jQuery?

Comment: @Vinay You're not helping. Please *do* the edit rather than commenting that an edit is required.

Answer (score 1):

I supose you have some sort of default option in your select that like

```
<option value="0">choose value</option>
```

If that is the case you want to validate when the user presses some button to continue that if the text input has some text then the select must have some option other than 0 selected

Just add this validation to the submit button

```
var allInputs = $(":input");
var allSelects= $(":select");
for(i = 0;i < allInputs.length; i++)
{
    if(allInputs[i].val() != "" && allSelects[i].val() == 0)
        return false
}
```

of course you should replace the input and select method if you have other inputs and selects. In that case just add some class and search for that

Comment: no value is stored in allInputs[i].val() .when i do alert(allInputs[i].val()) no alert has dispalyed

Comment: If your code is like you have it up there it's normal. Do you have any options added? like I wrote in my answer? Like this <option value="0">choose value</option>

Comment: nth-child should do the trick. Just search some information about it